# Groovy parse Json preserve keys order

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jsonslurper

I try to parse a Json in groovy/Jenkins(I have **no** access to `readJSON` step) and keep the json keys order.

After my research, I found that groovy `Map/HashMap` objects are not preserving the order of the keys.
The only type which keeping order is `LinkedHashMap` So I try to convert the output of `JsonSlurper.parseText` to linkedhashmap but it still changing the items order

```
def jsonstr = """
{
    "Id": 533,
    "StartTime": "2022-05-10 11:56:18",
    "EndTime": "2022-05-10 11:58:49",
    "TimeShift": "N/A",
    "Run": "123",
    "Setup": "Test",
    "Version": "3.17",
    "Result": "pass",
    "DebugMode": 1,
    "NumberOfCores": 3,
}
"""

//init as LinkedHashMap
LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap()
map = (LinkedHashMap) (new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsonstr))
println(map)
/*
the output is in incorrect order, I expect to get `Id` attribute as a first key but I'm getting: 
[EndTime:2022-05-10 11:58:49, Version:3.17, TimeShift:N/A, StartTime:2022-05-10 11:56:18, DebugMode:1, Run:123, NumberOfCores:3, Id:533, Setup:Test, Result:pass]
*/
```

Comment: That `parseText` method returns a `HashMap` object. Your cast is just converting that to a `LinkedHashMap`, which won't restore your original order. Not sure that's supported by `groovy.json.*`, you may want to find a more complete json parsing solution, such as jackson.

Comment: Ok got you, I'll try, any other suggestions except jackson?

Comment: I haven't used other options much, but there's also `gson`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:
I realized that `readJSON` step is keeping the order so I try to take a look at its implementation.

`readJSON` uses `net.sf.json.*` library, in this library there is an option to parse string to jsonObject (**with keeping the order of the keys!**) by:

```
import  net.sf.json.JSONSerializer

def map = JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonstr)
println(map)
```

NOTES:

1. if you want use it during a pipeline I suggest you to use `readJSON` step itself, otherwise, you'll need to approve this function from Manage Jenkins -> script approval
2. In this method empty properties will be `net.sf.json.JSONNull`
   which holds a textual value "null" -> `if (someEmptyKey != null)` always returns true (also when null) to avoid that, use:
   `if (!someEmptyKey instanceof JSONNull )`

Sources: [docs](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html), [jenkins-implementation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/977b73fe4d9f8599f34b0dc53058eb1f2b33aeb1/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/json/ReadJSONStepExecution.java#L115)